# Retrofit - Not calling API call when app is in background/closed

Tags: android, retrofit, android-service, android-workmanager

I am using Retrofit2 with OkHttp. Everything is working fine with it except the one thing 
- a network call when the app is closed or in background.'

**Working**

Whenever Firebase notification arrives, I make a network call to fetch data related to 
that notification and then show notification.

**Scenario**

Consider an Android app that is in the background or closed and notification arrived.

**What's Happening**

The notification arrives successfully, I can see it. But when I try to make a call, it
is always giving an error "java.net.SocketTimeoutException" Failed to connect to 
******* and I can't see any call coming on the server.

My Retrofit class

```
@Singleton
@Provides
static Retrofit provideRetrofitInstance(){
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.connectTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .callTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true);

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client.build())
            .build();
}
```

My Work Manager class

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    String encodedString = getInputData().getString(Constants.MODEL);

   // Starting foreground service
    setForegroundAsync(createForegroundInfo());

   //calling the api
  }
```

Initialize the work manager

```
 NotificationModel model = new NotificationModel(
                    intent.getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_MSG_TITLE),
                    intent.getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_MSG_BODY),
                    intent.getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_TYPE),
                    intent.getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_NOTIFCATION_ID),
                    intent.getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_SHOW),
                    intent.getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TYPE));

            String encodedModel = Helper.serializeToJson(model);

            Data createGroup = new Data.Builder()
                    .putString(Constants.MODEL , encodedModel)
                    .build();


            uploadWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(AlertWorker.class)
                    .setInputData(createGroup)
                    .build();

            WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(uploadWorkRequest);
```

Permissions in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" 
/>
```

Comment: That means its not able to connect to your server.  Check the URL you're using, and the network on the device.  If your server is local and not a real server with a public IP, make sure you're on the same wifi and you have your router configured to allow traffic to the server from other devices.  If you're on an emulator, remember that the base url is not 127.0.0.1, the emulator is its own device and they need to communicate over the virtual network between each other.

Comment: My URL is https and it's upload on the production server. It's working fine when the app is running but causing that issue when the app is in the background.  And also I am using the real device not an emulator. Thanks

Comment: How do you schedule your WorkManager class?

Comment: When notification received, I schedule the work manager

Comment: Can you show this code? I asked how, not when.

Comment: OneTimeWorkRequest uploadWorkRequest;
      uploadWorkRequest = 
                         new OneTimeWorkRequest
                        .Builder(AlertWorker.class)
                        .setInputData("New")
                        .build();

                WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(uploadWorkRequest);

Comment: I have added the full initialization in the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to do a background service ,so 
check this link https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Answer (score 0):

When enqueuing your job, I'd add a constraint which tells WorkManager that your job requires active network connection:

```
uploadWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(AlertWorker.class)
    .setInputData(createGroup)
    .setConstraints(new Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build())
    .build();

WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(uploadWorkRequest);
```

With this constraint your job will be executed once there's network.

Comment: After added the constraint, I found out that when the app is in the background there is no internet excess to my app. After opening the app, the work manager works successfully. I already have added internet permission in my manifest file. What can I do more to allow internet excess to my app when app is in the background? Thanks

Comment: On which phone do you test? Some phones implement strict rules for specific apps. Check if your app can be whitelisted

Comment: I am using Xiaomi (MI) phone. I have tested on Nexus and Huawei's phone and everything working perfectly there. Now, I am figuring out the issue in Xiaomi mobile.